# API Versioning: Follow Component or Facade Consistency?

Tags: openapi, versioning

Suppose I have a software component that follow some kind of versioning when released if production, for example 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 (the usual lifecycle) and expose a rest(ful) API with some OAS documentation attached to it. Should the version of the API follow the version of the component or if the facade of the API does not change among component versions, the version of the API should stay the same?